# C# Pass user input to method, and output result (from the main)?

Tags: c#

fairly new so please forgive the question.  I've written a method to take a string, covert it to a number, and return a Factorial of that number.  That works fine.  Its calling the method and printing the result that is confusing me.  Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type number to do factorial on..");
    var calc = Fact(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + calc);
}

private static string Fact(string numFact)
{
    var number = 1;
    int factorial = Convert.ToInt32(numFact);
    for (int i = 1; i<= factorial; i++)
    {
        number *= i;
    }
   // Console.WriteLine(number); added to test it works
    return numFact;
}
```

Can somebody help please?  As you'll probably guess from looking, If I input 5, I get 5 returned.

Comment: You are returning the wrong value. You want to `return number;` Also, change the function signature to `private static int Fact(string numFact)`

Comment: You are returning the same `numFact` number from the method which you are passing to it.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - instead of changing signature of the function, why not just `return number.ToString()`

Comment: @Fabio Well, since it's a math function, returning a number seems natural. But either way works.

Comment: and going on with @JohnnyMopp, the function should take an int as parameter, leaving the caller the conversion from string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type number to do factorial on..");
    var calc = Fact(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + calc);
}

private static int Fact(string numFact)
{
    var number = 1;
    int factorial = Convert.ToInt32(numFact);
    for (int i = 1; i<= factorial; i++)
    {
        number *= i;
    }
   // Console.WriteLine(number); added to test it works
    return number;
}
```

As the comments mention,

- You are returning `numFact` instead of `number`.
- You should make it return an `int` instead of `string` for a better practice, though this isn't exactly necessary, it just feels more natural since it is a number. Make it a string once you need it as a string, doing so early could cause problems later; however, since this is a very small project the likelihood of that is small so do what you like.

Comment: Ive edited your answer as you need to send it back ToString() because var number = 1 is an int the way the OP has written it. BTW thats not me thats marked you down on that one..

Comment: @SimonPrice I rejected it because you fail to notice that I switched the return type to `int` and not `string` the `Main` function should be fine since the OP uses `var` and integers concatenate with strings implicitly call `ToString()`.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  Much appreciated.  It did actually click before I came and checked, that I was returning the wrong value type!  Though I've picked up some other hints so this page isn't wasted! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You should dig a bit deeper with your logging.  You logged only 1 of 2 critical variables and so you didn't get the answers you needed from the logs.  Also, take the `Console.Readline()` out of the equation.  Use a hard coded number.  Eventually you can write tests.  Checkout [Test Driven Development](http://agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html) (TDD) which is perfect for this exercise.

Just modifying the logs without TDD can bring out something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("Type number to do factorial on..");
    int sampleNumber = 5;
    string sampleNumberAsString = sampleNumber.ToString();
    var calc = Fact(sampleNumberAsString);
    Console.WriteLine("Outside fact the answer is " + calc);
}


private static int Fact(string numFact)
{
    var number = 1;
    int factorial = Convert.ToInt32(numFact);
    for (int i = 1; i <= factorial; i++)
    {
        number *= i;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Inside Fact() local variable number is {number}");//Inside Fact() local variable number is 120
    Console.WriteLine($"Inside Fact() numFact parameter is is {numFact}");//Inside Fact() numFact parameter is is 5
    //return numFact;//Clearly I want to return the calculated value (number) not the original value passed in (numFact)
    //I'm calculating a number so let's not worry about what the caller does with the number
    //Change the return type to int.
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice.  Your right of course, though this is just for an exercise for myself, so not really necessary.  Though ill take this under advisement!